# Don't want superscript citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing, superscripts

By default, my citation form is in superscript as shown in the image below. I want the citation in the normal size (no superscript). Please let me know how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Without knowing what bibliography style you are using it is difficult to answer. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Well, using the default `biblatex` settings would "fix" it. Show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/48973).

Comment: I just realize that I had once put \usepackage[superscript]{cite} into the file, and now I just need to delete it to get the un-superscripted citation. Now, it's already fixed. Thank you for your time to answer my question...